# Android activities only for developers, should I leave them in the application release?

Tags: android, release

In my application I have a couple of activities that display stuff useful for developers, (or perform certain tasks only useful for developers). What should I do when I get to release the application?  Should I leave all that code in there (but hide it somehow) or should I just delete those activities? If I do delete them then development will slow down.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Gradle? There are a number of features of Gradle builds that could make this easier for you.

Comment: No, I am using Maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your developer features aren't particularly large (and thus won't take up too much space on the user's device), then the easiest way to hide them is to check the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` flag.

This flag is generated when your application is built, and will only be true when the build is debuggable. Since you can't upload a debuggable build to the Play Store, it will never be true for your users.

How you use it depends on how your developers are accessing it. If there's a button, you could conditionally hide the button.

Comment: As we are about to launch our beta- testing, I think that we'll keep everything for now. Thanks for the DEBUG tip. If they prove to consume too many resources, we may remove them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes - you should remove anything and everything that is unnecessary as they will consume resources. Just because the user does not have access to or sees these activities does not mean that they are not taking space up in memory.

If you are using Gradle, you can maintain a separate build for release without all these other extra activities.